# Closer Connected Components in Graph-Toll

Tags: python, graph-tool

I am using the python library Graph-Tool to create a network graph. There are about 6 distinct clusters/separate connected components in my graph. However, I would like them to be closer together in the graph. [image]

Basically, I don't want so much white space between the components. Is there a parameter I can tweak to change this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look a the documentation for `sfdp_layout` you will see many parameters:

https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.sfdp_layout

Why not experiment with some of them?

In particular, you might try changing the parameter `p`, which controls the exponent of the repulsive force between nodes.

Comment: I finally figured outn that sfdp is what controls the level of repulsion. Tweaking gamma and mu gave me what I was looking for. Thanks! Great tool.